# How can I make my generics code compatible with this method signature?

Tags: java, generics

I have a variation of the following code:

```
package com.test.package;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestClass {

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Called");
        }

    }

    public void method() {
        PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnable>();
        method2(queue);
    }

    public void method2(BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> queue) {
        System.out.println(queue);

        // Getting error here because BlockingQueue<? extends Runnable> is not a
        // subtype of BlockingQueue<Runnable>.
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(200, 200, 0L,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
    }
}
```

And as you can see, my queue is not compatible with the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor. Is there any way to work around this than cast my queue to `(BlockingQueue<Runnable>)`? I obviously can't patch Java Standard Library.

Comment: Why are you using `BlockingQueue<MyRunnable>` in the first place?

Comment: Because I have certain runnables with higher priority. I skipped the comparison part in my example, because it's unrelated to my question.

Comment: If it is unrelated, then maybe you could simply use `PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>`? It's not like `PriorityBlockingQueue` will stop sorting them if you do that.

Comment: One workaround is using raw types, but probably it is easier if you change your Queue to PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable> or use a different/custom Executor(Service) class (can you use ForkJoinPool?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *and you shouldn't*.

Your `BlockingQueue<MyRunnable>` should, of course, only contain `MyRunnable`s. But the `ThreadPoolExecutor` can submit arbitrary `Runnable` tasks to the queue you give it: see [`execute(Runnable command)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#1329).

If that happens, you could have a non-`MyRunnable` instance in your queue. You then try to poll from your reference of that queue (typed as a `BlockingQueue<MyRunnable>`), and get a `ClassCastException`.

Simple example:

```
PriorityBlockingQueue<MyRunnable> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(200, 200, 0L,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
threadPool.execute(new WhateverRunnable());
MyRunnable myRunnable = queue.poll(); // this could throw ClassCastException
```

The above code will throw an exception if the `queue.poll()` happens before the thread pool has had a chance to dequeue the `WhateverRunnable` instance.

Comment: The above code wont compile with a compilation error on the second line acording to my example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But if you added the explicit cast, it would -- and it'd be dangerous for the reasons I mentioned. That's why the type system doesn't let you do it (at least not without the explicit cast, and even the. It'll warn you that the cast is unsafe)